# Delimited List from Nested JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple JavaScript object that contains nested arrays. 
All I'm looking for here us to return a comma delimited list of the "productID' values that are present at "digitalData.transaction.item.productInfo[i].productID[j]"

I appreciate the help.

Here's an example of the JS (sorry for the length, but better dafe than sorry I guess):

```
window.digitalData = {
  transaction: {
    purchaseID: "30010819", //Typically the same as transactionID
    transactionID: "30010819", //Unique Identifier for this transaction
    item: [{ //Array of items in this transaction
      productInfo: {
        productID: "63493",
        color: "Fuscia", //color if this product has colors
        size: "M (8-10)", //size if this product has sizes
        sku: "63493-12456", //sku
        inventoryStatus: "In Stock", // Mirror the on-site messaging
        skuAttr: [{ // extensible array of sku attributes and values
          typeLabel: "Color",
          valueCode: "FSA",
          valueLabel: "Fuscia"
        }, {
          typeLabel: "Size",
          valueLabel: "M (8-10)"
        }]
      },
      price: {
        currency: "USD"
      },
      quantity: 1
    }, {
      productInfo: {
        productID: "55027",
        color: "", //color if this product has colors
        size: "", //size if this product has sizes
        sku: "55027", //sku if known. otherwise use productID
        inventoryStatus: "Low Stock", // Mirror the on-site messaging
        skuAttr: [] //Empty array if no sku attributes exist
      },
      price: {
        currency: "USD"
      },
      quantity: 2     
      }]
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it that way:

```
digitalData.transaction.item.map(x => x.productInfo.productID).join(',')
```